# Duplicate property name error with EF migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have the following properties defined in my `Agency` model:

```
public int AgencyCapturedById { get; set; }
public User AgencyCapturedBy { get; set; }
```

When I try an run an `Add-Migration` command, I get the following error:

> AgencyCapturedById: Name: Each property name in a type must be unique.
>   Property name 'AgencyCapturedById' is already defined.

To start with, if it was already defined elsewhere in class `Agency`, the project wouldn't build, and then, a search of the entire solution, for file types `*.*`, for the term `AgencyCapturedById` only yields one result, the line above where it is declared. Where could EF be finding another, identical property name? It's not even like I've used it before and removed it, so it might me haunting an assembly somewhere.

Comment: Any fluent code or inheritance? Does the agency table already exist?

Comment: No fluent code nor inheritance at the time I got the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be due to overriding the naming conventions? For example, I am able to generate this error with the following code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Properties()
                            .Where(p => p.Name == "Id")
                            .Configure(p => p.IsKey().HasColumnName(p.ClrPropertyInfo.ReflectedType == null ? "Id" : p.ClrPropertyInfo.ReflectedType.Name + "Id"));
}

public class Agency
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column("UserId")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User AgencyCapturedBy { get; set; }
}

[ComplexType]
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it appears due to my EF model builder conventions, having a property like `public User AgencyCapturedBy`, causes EF to automatically create a `public int AgencyCapturedById` property/column. I discovered this by commenting out the `Id` FK property, and found the migration still generated a new column with exactly that name.